# How to find a control of type in the entire controls chain?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I want to find all controls in my form that implement a certain interface (let's say `ITestInterface`). I have tried this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<ITestInterface>();
```

but it goe's only one level deep (despite what is written in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) - @dasblinkenlight), so if for example, I have a panel in the form and an `ITestInterface` control inside the panel, it will not find it.

How to do that?

---

**Edit:** As @HansPassant wrote in a comment, I could hard-code my panels name, however, I need a general solution, and not a specific solution to a particular form.

Comment: Hint: use recursion.  (Control.Controls / Control.Parent)

Comment: Consider panel1.Controls instead of this.Controls

Comment: @HansPassant - I need the solution to be general and not specific to a particular form.

Comment: You did not write a "general solution".  It is not clear what help you need, given that Peter's comment should certainly be helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant - I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use recursion and step through the `Controls` property of your controls:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetAllOfType<T>(Control rootControl)
{
    return rootControl.Controls.OfType<T>().
           Concat(rootControl.Controls.OfType<Control>().SelectMany(GetAllOfType<T>));

}
```

You can use this like:

```
var allOfTestInterface = GetAllOfType<ITestInterface(this);
```

It takes all controls with that interface that are directly contained by the root control (with your `OfType<>()` call) and then calls the method again for *all* controls contained by that control, thus recursing through all containers. `SelectMany` flattens this nested lists into one list.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, the wording is rather vague, they don't really say nested controls are included, they say you can use `Controls` to "iterate through all controls of a form, including nested controls", that's not 100% the same ;)